# Magento 2.4 - Catalog search index process unknown error

Tags: magento2, catalog, catalogsearch, index, magento2.4.0

I am getting a catalog search index process unknown error when I run

> `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

I don't know how to solve this. I have successfully connected to `Elasticsearch 7` on the admin panel.

Attached is a *screenshot.*

[image: Magento 2 error to reindex catalog search]

Comment: It looks like permission issue

Comment: What type of permission

Comment: Check Apache server error log and might be elasticsearch folder permission issue

Comment: I am running my website online